# Error 'vmlinux' while compiling Android kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I would like to try RAM extraction for Android devices (Nexus 5X with Android 6.0.1). To create the proper Lime and Volatility kernel module, I have to create the System.map file. I have to compile my own kernel to achive that.
My steps so far:

- download repository for Nexus 5X:

  ```
  git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/
  ```
- download proper toolchain for cross compiling:

  ```
  git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9
  ```
- recheck version:

  ```
  export PATH=/root/compile/msm/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin:$PATH
  aarch64-linux-android-gcc -v
  $: gcc version 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease) (GCC)
  ```
- Check out proper kernel build (in my case 710c22a)

  ```
  cd msm
  git checkout 710c22a
  ```
- prepare environment variables for kernel build

  ```
  export ARCH=arm64
  export SUBARCH=arm64
  export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
  make bullhead_defconfig
  make -j4
  ```

Up to now, everything worked. The make process did its work until this error:

```
aarch64-linux-android-ld: cannot find libgcc.a: No such file or directory
aarch64-linux-android-ld: cannot find libgcc.a: No such file or directory
Makefile:806: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
root@kali:~/:#
```

The block with line 806 in Makefile is:

```
# Include targets which we want to
# execute if the rest of the kernel build went well.
vmlinux: scripts/link-vmlinux.sh $(vmlinux-deps) FORCE
ifdef CONFIG_HEADERS_CHECK
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/Makefile headers_check
endif
ifdef CONFIG_SAMPLES
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=samples
endif
ifdef CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=Documentation
endif
    +$(call if_changed,link-vmlinux) # This is line 806 where error occurs
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem? Or where I can get help with this problem?
The whole Makefile (1500 lines) is here:

https://pastebin.com/ZHDWXjDB

Comment: Did you search for the file? That is the a static version of the libgcc, which should be the appropriate one for architecture arm64. But I don't understand why does it have to link to it. The Makefile is not clear at all. Post the whole Makefile if you can, and if it's not that long.

Comment: There are only some libgcc.h files, but no libgcc.a . I posted a Pastebin link with the whole Makefile

Comment: THANK YOU! I looked for the file on my whole hard drive, and there was a libgcc.a file in the androideabi folder (a cross compile I used before but did not work). I pasted it into the proper folder and now it works :)

Comment: I am very glad, please delete the question then.